# Inspecting overlapping elements in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In the Chrome developer tools, using the inspect element tool, if two elements on the page occupy the same space only the one with the highest z-index seems accessible with the mouse. Is there some keyboard shortcut or some other way to cycle through elements if multiple elements are under the cursor location?

[Here's a crappy example](https://jsbin.com/winukuzasu/edit?html,css,output):

[image]

There's a div with a red border positioned behind and entirely inside another div with a blue border. Mousing over the red one with the inspector tool selects the blue one. Can I select the red one with the mouse?

Also I just noticed; even right-clicking that red area and choosing "inspect element" inspects the blue element not the red one. So the behavior isn't just limited to the inspect element tool.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior isn't just limited to the Inspect Element tool in Chrome,
but also to every browser and such tool that I have ever tried.

My solution to such cases, when I wish to delete an element that is
impossible to select, is to open up the Development Tools,
position as close as possible to the problem element,
locate it in the HTML where a click selects just this element,
then delete it from there.

This method works in every browser that has Development Tools,
which is basically all the browsers.
It's more work, but it's effective every time.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that's my usual method too except sometimes the element is far away in the dom from anything close to it in the rendered page, so it's really hard to locate. That's actually what prompted the question :)

Comment: Most tools pre-select the element when the cursor passes over it. This makes it easy to skip rapidly over the HTML all around. The problem for Inspect Element (and others) is when the CSS causes an element to appear elsewhere than in its "natural" position and size.

Answer (score -1):

I have written the folowing HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
#myBlue {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
border 5px #040BA6 solid;        left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: aqua;
    display:block;
}
#myRed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
border 5px #EE0E12 solid;        left: 20px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display:block;
    background-color:lightpink ;
}
body{
    background-color: azure;
}
</style> 
</head>

<body>
    <div ID="myRed" contenteditable>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div ID="myBlue" contenteditable>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I get when I inspect using Chrome's dev tools: https://youtu.be/Nkeo938T804. I think this is what you want, so it works fine for me. It MUST be a version issue. I have MS Edge 86 on Win 10 2020. I tried with Chromium 88, it worked well too. Good luck